# Using powerline adapter over 3 floors

Tags: electrical

I have been using a powerline adapter without a hitch for a few years now, but I am moving from a ground floor bungalow, to a 3 floored house.

Will the powerline adapters still work over the different floors, or is it likely they are on a separate loop?

Comment: Powerline adapter for what?

Comment: @keshlam Powerline ethernet

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're on different floors is mostly irrelevant. It's often the case that different rooms are on different branch circuits even on the same floor.

This type of system relies on simple continuity of two or more of the three legs (hot, neutral, ground). In a properly wired system they should work, but you'll have to try to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine, even on different circuits.  (It might work with one unit in the neighbor's house - no kidding!)

Comment: Not sure that blanket statements like this are ok with Powerline...  I've tried them in a one story, older home and they didn't work at all.  They _should_ be ok, but there's certainly a chance they will work poorly or not at all.  In my two story speeds were too slow for streaming HD video.

Comment: That's true, powerline IME is nice and convenient when it works, but it either just works or it just doesn't - sometimes even at short distances.